# How do I add Board Columns and Swimlanes to my Iterations in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, kanban

We have an on premises install of TFS 2015.

In the Requirements Backlog, we can add Board Columns and Swimlanes, but these do not show up under any of the iterations.
Our iterations only have Proposed, Active, Resolved, and Closed.

How do I add new Board Columns and Swimlanes to our iterations?
We would also like to be able to split the columns for doing and done in the Board Column on the iterations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Custom sprint board columns are not available yet, only backlog board.

There is a UserVoice request for it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3229015-customize-the-columns-on-the-task-board

Comment: May 2016 looks like they mention they are working on it... Its now November.. working on it!  :-(